# Loopback rest-connector

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

Any examples of working with multiple templates in multiple URL calls in loopback(apart from the one mentioned in the documentation example, external, local server one).

For ex. GET -> (URL : http://localhost:xxxx/function1) ; POST -> (URL : http://localhost:xxxx/function2).
How to handle these calls specifically. Kindly provide your thoughts.

Thanks.